# iOS app status bar colors

Tags: ios, statusbar, status

I'm working with an common code to change all screens status bar but for some reason just one screen (like the example) is with the default color. Why this happen?

[image]

My Code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = colorWithHexString("FFFFFF")
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.05, green: 0.27, blue: 0.11, alpha: 0.5)
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

Comment: is this view controller is embed in navigation controller with push or show segue or you are presenting it modally

Comment: Check `View controller-based status bar appearance` property in info.plist.. It should be `NO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Swift

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

## Objective-C

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

If it's not working set value to View controller-based status bar appearance in ProjectName -> (Targets) Info section -> Custom iOS Target Properties to NO.

Answer (score 0):

`I'm working with an common code to change all screens status`

There is a one stop solution for this. Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in `info.plist` to `No` and in app target settings under General tab select a default Status Bar Style

[image]

No coding is required:)